# Change DatePickerDialog's button texts

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm having some trouble changing the text of the buttons of the dialog.

I tried to use:

```
setButton(int whichButton,
          CharSequence text,
          DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

and

```
setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, Message msg)
```

But I could not figure out what to put as the third parameter. I could pass a new `OnClickListener`, but I would like to use the callback `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

I guess when I set a new `Listener` to the `Button` the `DateSetListener` won't ne called anymore?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

setButton ist the correct approach. As listener just pass the dialog object itself, because the `onDateSetListener` gets passed with the constructor of the dialog.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear_g, mMonth_g, mDay_g); 
dpd.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Button Text", dpd);
```

Comment: dpd.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Button Text", (OnClickListener)null);

Answer (score 0):

```
        val now = Calendar.getInstance()

        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )

        datePickerDialog.setOkText("set apply button text")
        datePickerDialog.setCancelText("set cancel button text")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('input[name="dates2"]').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
       cancelLabel: 'Clear',
       applyLabel:'Change'
      }
```