# Custom DatePicker buttons

Tags: android, datepicker, xamarin

I would like to highlight that I am looking for a Xamarin solution.  I have found Java solutions, but I can't seem to convert them to Xamarin.  I want to have the user set their birthday and then have the app calculate their age, and display it as text. I have everything functioning.  
All I am looking to do is change the text on the "ok" button to "Calculate age."  I am able to change the text, but the button doesn't grab the date from the picker then.  This is how I create my datepicker:

```
  DatePickerDialog setDate = new DatePickerDialog(this, onDateSet, date.Year, date.Month-1, date.Day);
```

then I use this method to change the text

```
  setDate.SetButton("calculate age", EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)
```

I have created an `EventHandler` called Age use for the second argument.  What code do I put in the `EventHandler` to make the button function like the "ok" button?   if I set `handler:null` the method works, I can also get the method to do other things, change text in textbox for a example. Any solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. No love for Xamarin?  I discovered the solution was much simpler.  Following from what I learned here: [Change DatePickerDialog's button texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218069/change-datepickerdialogs-button-texts).  I began throwing darts into the code and this is what stuck.  Where I set handler to null I simply set listener to the dialog object like so. `setDate.SetButton ("calculate age", listener:setDate);`